# Vue3 bind props to slot

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am wondering if it is possible to bind properties to the component slot's child.

I am using `vuetify` framework and its `v-tooltip` component. I find it tedious to `v-bind` props onto each child element, so I would like to make a global component, which would do it for me. The idea, but not a working example is below:

```
// AppTooltip.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{ text: string }>()
</script>

<template>
  <v-tooltip :text="props.text">
    <template #activator="{ props }">
      <slot v-bind="props" />
    </template>
  </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

I would then like to use it like this:

```
<AppTooltip text="Save changes">
   <v-btn @click="save">
      Save
   </v-btn>
</AppTooltip>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did would force you to reapply the props given to the `AppTooltip` to the `v-btn` again.

Although in vuetify 3 there is another way to not write this boilerplate.

```html
<v-btn>
  The Btn's text
  <v-tooltip activator="parent">
    Tooltip Text
  </v-tooltip>
</v-btn>
```

The `activator="parent"` can be used for menus, dialogs and other components that have `activator` slot too.